# Reuse columns in dbt model

Tags: yaml, dbt

I am defining a dbt model configuration to create a set of tables that have a number of common columns. Currently the YAML file looks like this:

```yaml
version: 2

models:
  - name: table1
    columns:
      - name: id
        description: The identifier
      - name: attribute1
        description: Attribute 1
  - name: table2
    columns:
      - name: id
        description: The identifier
      - name: attribute2
        description: Attribute 2
```

I would like this to be more DRY, so I tried using the `<<:` merge operator which works somehow but it does not retain the information about the column descriptions for some reason:

```yaml
version: 2

.comm: &comm
  columns:
    - name: id
      description: The identifier

models:
  - name: table1
    <<: *comm
    columns:
      - name: attribute1
        description: Attribute 1
  - name: table2
    <<: *comm
    columns:
      - name: attribute2
        description: Attribute 2
```

Am I missing something? Are there other options to avoid repeating the same set of columns in the YAML file defining a dbt model configuration?

Edit: the set of common columns would be quite large and each column would have its own description, data type and tests.

Answer (score 1):

[Doc Blocks](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/collaborate/documentation#using-docs-blocks) are meant for this use case, which allow you to write your definitions in a single place (a `.md` file), and then reference them in multiple descriptions or `.yml` files.

**Define your doc block**

```
{% docs id %}
unique identifier
{% enddocs %}
```

**Reference it in a YAML file**

```
columns:
  - name: id
    description: '{{ doc("id") }}'
  - name: another_id
    description: '{{ doc("id") }}'
```

You can also consider using [dbt-labs/dbt-codegen](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-codegen#generate_model_yaml-source) to create the scaffolding for your column documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for. Imagine that the set of common columns is large and that each of them has the same tests, data types and referential integrity constraints. It looks like Doc Blocks should be used for single fields in the YAML (e.g. `description`), not entire blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Your concern may be similar https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/1790 that is not yet supported by dbt.